# What is the purpose of storing local events in the `EventQueue`?

Tags: events

In Sitecore databases, the `EventQueue` table contains both local and remote events of Sitecore instances.

Why is there a need to track local events? Can't they just be handled internally in the instance that fired them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes many types of events can be handled locally, not required to be shared to other servers.

See solution #2 at https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/930920 -- using the FileBasedPropertyStore has reduced volume of the EventQueue by 60% or more for some of the large implementations I've worked with.  It shifts the specific events to the file system of IIS instead of SQL Server.

Comment: Why do these events need to be stored somewhere, at all? Can't they be kept in memory?

Comment: I can't speak for "all" the events since I'm not certain what they all do, but mostly the local-only ones I've seen are for data like timestamps for when an index was last modified etc.  I would think persisting that beyond app pool recycles would be important, but maybe not in all cases.